# Why do I get this error in flutter using velocity_x navigator? Error: Type 'VxObserver' not found. class MyObs extends VxObserver

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter to create a web app. Why do I get this error using velocity_x package? Error: Type 'VxObserver' not found. class MyObs extends VxObserver. I am trying to setup a navigation system in the app.